# System.InvalidCastException while inheriting a class

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, polymorphism

I've created a class for a binary search tree called `BSTree`. I want to create a class for AVL tree called `AVLTree` and inherit `BSTree` class. But when I override a virtual method from `BSTree` class in `AVLTree` class and want to perform type casting from `BSTree` to `AVLTree` using round brackets notation, for example, `AVLTree node = (AVLTree)base.SomeMethod(...)`, the error **System.InvalidCastException: "Unable to cast object of type 'BSTree.BSTree' to type 'BSTree.AVLTree'."** occurs.

My `BSTree` class looks like this (I remained only necessary part of it):

```
class BSTree
{
    public int Value { get; private set; }
    public BSTree Left { get; set; }
    public BSTree Right { get; set; }
    public BSTree Parent { get; set; }
    public BSTree(int value) { Value = value; }
    protected virtual BSTree InsertBase(int value)
    {
        BSTree node = this, parent = null;
        while (node != null)
        {
            if (value == node.Value) return null;
            parent = node;
            node = value > node.Value ? node.Right : node.Left;
        }
        node = new BSTree(value);
        node.Parent = parent;
        if (value > parent.Value) parent.Right = node;
        else parent.Left = node;
        return node;
    }
    public virtual void Insert(int value) { InsertBase(value); }
}
```

My `AVLTree` class (with a function for inserting only) looks like this:

```
class AVLTree : BSTree
{
    public int BalanceFactor { get; set; }
    public AVLTree(int value) : base(value) { }
    protected override BSTree InsertBase(int value)
    {
        AVLTree node = (AVLTree)base.InsertBase(value); // error happens there
        // following operations that calculate balance factors for all ancestors
        return node;
    }
}
```

I want `AVLTree` nodes to be inserted in exact the same manner as `BSTree` nodes, but `AVLTree` nodes need to have also a `BalanceFactor` property, apart from `Left`, `Right` and `Parent`, that come from `BSTree` class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here the base class creates the `node` object that it later returns:

```
node = new BSTree(value);
```

This object is *always* of the type `BSTree`, so can never be downcast to an inherited type.

If you want to make this variable, you could consider making use of the [Factory Method pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern). Something like this:

```
node = CreateNode(value);
```

where `CreateNode` is a `virtual` method that a deriving class can override.